# Java: Find out if an applet is showing on Screen

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, visibility

I'm trying to write an applet in Java that checks if it is showing on the screen. 
There are several methods to check if Java wants to show the applet or specific components (i.e. `.isShowing()` or `.isVisible()` ) but none of them check if the application is really visible on screen.

Let's say you start the applet in Tab A of your favorite browser. When you move to Tab B, the applet isn't showing anymore, but still running (applet.stop() won't be called in this case). Or when you have the page with the applet but move another before it. I need to check if the applet is really visible to the user, not hidden by any other thing (like being behind  another application, for example.)

I think there is no easy way to do this in java, since I googled the last 2 days for it ;) Can anybody tell me some way to achieve this ? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(applet, "Do U C Me?") // requires Motivated End User API`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with applets, but from what I understand, you do not need to check if it's `Visible` or `Showing`, you need to check if it's `Active. 
Check this java code ->  [Java Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#isActive%28%29)

Or you could define a rang on the screen and detect when the mouse exceeds that. So in this case, you will know if the user is working on something else even if the applet is showing. (user open two browser at the same time on the screen)

Comment: isActive() returns true if the applet loads, but this wouldn't solve my problem - I'm trying to check if the user can see the applet (or the page where the applet loads). 

Also the second option wouldn't work because when the applet is hidden by another application and the user stays within the bounds provided, you would get an incorrect true result.

Comment: Well, I made an assumption that if the browser window is not active, then the applet will be not active as well. How could it detect the mouse moment when another window or app is in place?

Best of luck.

Comment: This is easy .... with MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() you check the location on screen and let the Thread.sleep() ... then after a time you call the method again, and if its the same coordinates, then the mouse hasn't been moved (or at least been moved to the exact position as before.)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem via `Frame.isFocused()`.

Comment: `isFocused` determines if the program currently has keyboard focus, it could be displayed on the screen, but not have focus...